# K-Fold Cross Validation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have data of 36 users

as shown in the code (MATLAB) data is loaded into a matrix called **Feat_Vec1**

```
 clear;
  for nc = 1 : 36  % nc number of users
              % Load data into MATLAB
      data{nc} = load( sprintf('U%02d_Acc_TimeD_FreqD_FDay.mat', nc) );  

             % assign data into Matrix
      Feat_Vec1{nc} = data{nc}.Acc_TD_Feat_Vec(:,:);   

 end
```

for each user, I have 36 rows and 143 columns as a result,  **Feat_Vec1** contains **36 cells** (number of users) and each cell contains **36 rows and 143 columns**

I'd like to use **9-Fold Cross Validation** in order to divide my dataset into training and testing.

I have seen this the [documentation in MATLAB help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) but don't understand it ! 
wondering if someone help me with the coding of 9-Fold Cross Validation for each user?

Comment: Do you want subject-independent cross validation?

Comment: Dear Jeff, yeah I want to divide the data each user independently . Regards.

Comment: Then `crossvalind` won't be enough, AFAIK. But since you already have the data separated, you can just create a fold vector that looks like `[1, 1, ..., 1, 2, 2, ..., 2, 3, ...]`

Comment: Dear @jeff i dont get what do you mean? could you please help me with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will modify your code to show how a 9-fold cross-validation can be done for each user independently. That means, each user will have its own train-test folds. First of all, 9-fold cross-validation means to user 8/9-th data for training and 1/9-th for testing. Repeat this nine times.

```
clear;
for nc = 1:36  % nc number of users
    % probably you don't need to save data in a cell - like data{nc}
    data = load( sprintf('U%02d_Acc_TimeD_FreqD_FDay.mat', nc));
    data = data.Acc_TD_Feat_Vec(:,:);
    ind = crossvalind('Kfold', 36, 9);
    for fold = 1:9
        Feat_Vec1_train{nc}{fold} = data(ind ~= fold, :)  
        Feat_Vec1_test{nc}{fold} = data(ind == fold, :)    
    end
end
```

In the above code, there are 9 pairs of train and test sets for each user. For example, 8th fold of train-test pair for 3rd user can be accessed as:

```
Feat_Vec1_train{3}{8}
Feat_Vec1_test{3}{8}
```

Comment: Please note that dividing each user into train-test folds is not user-independent cross validation. That's why I said `crossvalind` is not enough for this.

Comment: so, what i should do @jeff? i know i am bothering you but could you please solve it for me?

Comment: Dear @Parag S. Chandakkar I really appreciate your kind effort to help me. Actually, there are two problems in the above code. Firstly the training data is the same size of the original user's data.( which means when I run your code Feat_Vec1_train of user1 contains 36 values for each column while Feat_Vec1_test is empty). It supposes Feat_Vec1_train contains 32 values in each column ( repeat that nine times) and Feat_Vec1_test contains 4 values ( repeat that nine times)

Comment: @jeff Is there any specific meaning to the term "user-independent cross validation". [Searching didn't help](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=user-independent+cross+validation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Anyway, I am generating `ind` for each user. That is why I said << how a 9-fold cross-validation can be done for each user independently >>. This is what I understood from OP's question in which he says: "9-Fold Cross Validation for each user".

Comment: @NeamahAl-Naffakh I think you figured out that `i` needed to be replaced by `fold`.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I'm not sure which one OP wants, but what I meant was a test where all data from one user is either in the training or testing fold, not mixed. That's a better estimate of performance on unseen subjects.

Comment: @jeff Yes. I agree with you. Depends on the OP what he wants.

Comment: @jeff,@ParagS.Chandakkar. many thanks for your help and support. jeff, all I want is the data that appear in the training matrix is not going to be in the testing matrix ( repeat that 9 times). In other words, every value in one column will be used in the training and testing only one time and actually the code of Parag is acheived what i want. I just replaced (i) by (fold).

Comment: OK, but in this case, you have testing samples from subjects that are seen in the training set. Although the samples are unique, subjects are not. You will have seen other samples from the same subject in the training set, which can optimistically change your results.

Comment: @jeff what do you mean by ''Although the samples are unique, subjects are no''t? based on the written code, i guess  every sample will appear one time in the testing,  for example, 10 cross validation for 40 samples means each bin contains 4 samples ( 36 samples for training and 4 for testing). this will be repeated 10 times . however, each test has 4 unique samples for testing, i know these samples will appear in the training at one stage but these samples can not be appear in the training and testing at the same time!

Comment: @NeamahAl-Naffakh in an ideal subject-independent setting, **all** the samples from one subject resides either in the training or testing fold. In other words, you should not train with `[subj1_samp1, subj1_samp2]` and test with `[subj1_samp3]`. It's not a realistic estimate of performance on unseen data.

Comment: how come mate? if all his samples reside in the training how we can do the testing? or if all his samples in the testing how we can do the training?

Comment: @NeamahAl-Naffakh If all the samples are in testing, you train with other subjects. If all are in training, it's a training subject.. :) Note that when you average all folds, you will have all samples evaluated as both training and testing subjects.

Comment: dear @jeff , for authentication purpose, you need to divide the samples of the same user into two parts,  training and testing samples. without testing samples how can you know if the user will be authenticated by the system or not ?   by the way, could you mind to have a quick look at this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040037/training-neural-network-for-user-recognition-in-matlab

Comment: OK, sorry I didn't understand this was an authentication task :)

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your code:

```
% Combine data into a single matrix:
data = []; % sorry for the dynamic allocation
for i=1:36
    data = [data; Feat_Vec1{nc}];
end

N = size(data, 1); % should be 36^2 = 1296
K = 9;
% create a vector that have K (=9) blocks of length N/K, such as [1 1 ... 1 2 2 ... 2 ... 9 9 ... 9 ]
folds = []; % again, sorry for the dynamic allocation
for i=1:K
    folds = [folds; repmat(i, N/K, 1)];
end
```

Now you determined the fold indices. Collecting the data into a single matrix was not necessary at this point, since we already knew `N`. But this variable might be useful when using your data for training and testing in a for loop:

```
accuracies = zeros(1, K);
for fold = 1:K
   testIds = find(folds==fold);
   trainIds = find(folds~=fold);
   % train your algorithm
   model = train(data(trainIds,:), label(trainIds,:), etc);
   % evaluate on the testing fold
   accuracies(fold) = test(model, data(testIds,:), label(testIds,:), etc);
end
mean(accuracy)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Dear @jeff many thanks for you help and support. Actully you mixed the data of all users into one matrix? and i dont want to do that. i want to have the data of each user separately. for example, user1 has 36 values in each column, I'd like to do 9 cross validation ( which means for user1, 9 values from each column will be stored for testing and 27 values of each column will be used to train his model. this precedure will be repeated 9 times , finally i will take the average of 9 different tests). does that make sense please?. again many thanks for your help

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I tried to do in the for loop :)

Comment: @NeamahAl-Naffakh Please check my answer if it suits your needs.

Comment: Dear@jaff really sorry to bother you again but i dont get your code! when i run it gives me error! code you please try again please?

Comment: Dear @Parag S. Chandakkar could you please see my last comments? because as I mentioned for all users  Feat_Vec1_train  contains 36 values for each column while Feat_Vec1_test is empty

Comment: dear@jeff, could you explain to me the second part of your first code because when i run it, it get an error,           Undefined variable label.

Error in cross_validation (line 52)
   model = train(data(trainIds,:), label(trainIds,:), etc);

Comment: Yes, I assumed you also had a label vector of size `1296 x 1`. You don't?

Comment: dear@jeff,what do you mean by i had a label vector of size 1296 x 1. i just run your code as it is with my previous code! and when i run it i have this error as i mentioned before                                                                                        ((   Undefined variable label.

Error in cross_validation (line 52)
   model = train(data(trainIds,:), label(trainIds,:), etc);  ))

Comment: Yes, because currently the variable label does not exist. Do you have labels, i.e. a target variable that you want to estimate? What do you want to achieve with cross-validation?

Answer (score 1):

just a little correction to the code above

```
clear;
for nc = 1:36  % nc number of users
    % probably you don't need to save data in a cell - like data{nc}
    data = load( sprintf('U%02d_Acc_TimeD_FreqD_FDay.mat', nc));
    data = data.Acc_TD_Feat_Vec(:,:);
    ind = crossvalind('Kfold', 36, 9);
    for fold = 1:9
        Feat_Vec1_train{nc}{fold} = data(ind ~= fold, :)  
        Feat_Vec1_test{nc}{fold} = data(ind == fold, :)    
    end
end
```